How to properly limit a String for VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) in Oracle?
We are using VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) columns in our oracle database to store JSON data without compromising performance too much by using CLOB. I've learned that 4000 CHAR is technically limited to 4000 BYTE, which is the maximum length for all those string columns. Even NVARCHAR2 ist limited to these 4000 BYTE.
That's why we try to split our Strings on the Java side of code to chunks of 4000 bytes. To determine the real length of the String in the database we use String#getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length. This doesn't seem to work reliably. Oracle sometimes throws the following error nevertheless:

ORA-12899: Wert zu groß für Spalte
"OUR_DATABASE"."HISTORICAL_DATASETS"."JSON1" (aktuell: 4006,
maximal: 4000)

The encoding used by Oracle is ALS32UTF8 – according to SELECT parameter, value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'.
What am I missing? Is there any additional overhead despite the encoding itself?
EDIT: Here is the #split method used:
public static List<String> split(String input, int size, boolean inBytes, Charset charset) {
    List<String>  parts   = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder segment = new StringBuilder();
    int           length  = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        String c = input.substring(i, i+1); // charAt(i);

        // Wie viele Bytes ein Zeichen ggf. wirklich beansprucht, hängt von der Codierung ab!
        int realLength = inBytes ? c.getBytes(charset).length : 1;

        if (realLength > size) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Der Parameter <size> muss mindestens so groß sein," +
                                                                  " dass jedes der Zeichen dort reinpasst! " + size +
                                                                  " ist aktuell leider zu klein für " + realLength + " Bytes.");

        // Wenn die aktuelle Länge das Limit überschreitet, speichern wir den aktuellen Teil.
        if (length + realLength > size) {
            parts.add(segment.toString());
            segment   = new StringBuilder();
            length = 0;
        }

        segment.append(c);
        length += realLength;
    }

    // Füge den letzten Teil hinzu, falls noch etwas übrig ist.
    if (segment.length() > 0) {
        parts.add(segment.toString());
    }

    return parts;
}

And this is my setter:
public void setJson(@NotNull String json) {
     if (json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length > 5 * MAX_VARCHAR) {
        this.jsonShort1 = null;
        this.jsonShort2 = null;
        this.jsonShort3 = null;
        this.jsonShort4 = null;
        this.jsonShort5 = null;
        this.jsonLong   = json;
    }
    else {
        List<String> split = StringUtils.split(json, MAX_VARCHAR, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        this.jsonShort1 = split.size() > 0 ? split.get(0) : null;
        this.jsonShort2 = split.size() > 1 ? split.get(1) : null;
        this.jsonShort3 = split.size() > 2 ? split.get(2) : null;
        this.jsonShort4 = split.size() > 3 ? split.get(3) : null;
        this.jsonShort5 = split.size() > 4 ? split.get(4) : null;
        this.jsonLong   = null;
    }
}

For the following fields:
@Lob                          private String jsonLong;
@Column(length = MAX_VARCHAR) private String jsonShort1;
@Column(length = MAX_VARCHAR) private String jsonShort2;
@Column(length = MAX_VARCHAR) private String jsonShort3;
@Column(length = MAX_VARCHAR) private String jsonShort4;
@Column(length = MAX_VARCHAR) private String jsonShort5;

EDIT #2:
Here some more details on the performance difference between CLOB and VARCHAR in my case. Using a local docker image running Oracle DB and a local JBoss EAP.
Using the following quick and dirty API:
package my.test;

import my.model.HistoricalDataset;
import my.utils.LoremIpsum;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/A1E-16094")
public class A1E_16094 {

    @Inject private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Path("/generate")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Transactional
    public String generate() {
        long max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            String string = LoremIpsum.getWords(2000);
            this.em.persist(HistoricalDataset.useVARCHAR(string));
            this.em.persist(HistoricalDataset.useCLOB(string));
            max = Math.max(max, string.length());
        }
        return "2x 50.000 EntityManager#persist() mit bis zu " + max + " Zeichen als VARCHAR + CLOB\n";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/loadVARCHAR")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String loadVARCHAR() {
        List<HistoricalDataset> datasets = this.em.createQuery("from HistoricalDataset where uuidTable = 'VARCHAR'",
                                                               HistoricalDataset.class).getResultList();
        return datasets.size() + " Datensätze mit VARCHAR geladen\n";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/loadCLOB")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String loadCLOB() {
        List<HistoricalDataset> datasets = this.em.createQuery("from HistoricalDataset where uuidTable = 'CLOB'",
                                                               HistoricalDataset.class).getResultList();
        return datasets.size() + " Datensätze mit CLOB geladen\n";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/delete")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Transactional
    public String delete() {
        int count = this.em.createQuery("delete from HistoricalDataset where uuidTable in ('CLOB', 'VARCHAR')")
                .executeUpdate();
        return count + " Datensätze mit VARCHAR + CLOB wieder gelöscht\n";
    }
}

These are my results:
daniel@McPherson:./jboss-eap-7.4 $ curl -s -w "Zeit: %{time_total}s\n" http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/A1E-16094/generate
2x 50.000 EntityManager#persist() mit bis zu 12452 Zeichen als VARCHAR + CLOB
Zeit: 97.379629s
daniel@McPherson:./jboss-eap-7.4 $ curl -s -w "Zeit: %{time_total}s\n" http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/A1E-16094/loadVARCHAR
50000 Datensätze mit VARCHAR geladen
Zeit: 7.544128s
daniel@McPherson:./jboss-eap-7.4 $ curl -s -w "Zeit: %{time_total}s\n" http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/A1E-16094/loadCLOB
50000 Datensätze mit CLOB geladen
Zeit: 43.838948s
daniel@McPherson:./jboss-eap-7.4 $ curl -s -w "Zeit: %{time_total}s\n" http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/A1E-16094/delete
100000 Datensätze mit VARCHAR + CLOB wieder gelöscht
Zeit: 30.284013s
daniel@McPherson:./jboss-eap-7.4 $ 


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE statement for you table; the Java code that you are using to split and insert the strings; and an example of the sample data that is causing the issue. Without any code we cannot see what you are doing and cannot comment on "what you are missing".

I would have thought performance is going to be affected more by storing 12000 bytes of JSON in 3 VARCHAR2 columns or rows and then having to retrieve multiple columns/rows and concatenate them every time you want to read the data rather than using one CLOB/BLOB/JSON column?

No. From my tests with our databases the CLOB is much slower when loading those rows than loading multiple columns (single row) of VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE). I'd need to stress test this for reliable numbers – but from my initial testing CLOB is more then 10x slower. This might heavily depend on the type of storage used.

As for a reproducible example I'll need a little more time. I'm just experiencing those errors and still try to figure out, what's the string causing it. It happens on a remote system with limited access.

I've just added more code.

Looks like a headache, and I have to say, I tend to agree with @MT0 about 'false optimization'. Also, your JSON is likely to be able to compress to a significant degree

Nevertheless I'd like to understand that 4000 BYTE limit and its encoding restrictions. Even if I might manage to reverse that splitting of the CLOB. Also: this is a compromise with Oracle DB instead of a better fit like MongoDB or something similar. I'm bound to fixed environments and an already productive system landscape.

Astral characters (codepoints above U+FFFF)? In a German context, they're not likely, but your Java code is not correct for dealing with them. In particular this line:
int realLength = inBytes ? c.getBytes(charset).length : 1;

Since Java strings are UTF-16, astral characters are encoded as surrogate pairs, ie. one Unicode code point is two Java Characters in this case. Since you're going character by character, you are splitting the surrogate pair, and so c does not contain valid Unicode. Per the documentation, this results in a "default replacement byte array," which I tested via an online compiler to simply be 0xFF.
So in the end your code would evaluate astral characters (both surrogate pairs together) as having a total of length 2 whereas they are actually length 4 in UTF-8. Additionally, the pair are evaluated separately meaning you might accidentally split them across the 4000 byte chunks.
If you can guarantee valid UTF-16 Java strings (surrogates are correct) then in the context of your code, I think the following would work by effectively placing the 4 bytes on the lead surrogate to prevent splitting the surrogate pair:
int realLength = 1;
if (inBytes) {
    if (c >= '\uD800' && c <= '\uDBFF') realLength = 4;
    else if (c >= '\uDC00' && c <= '\uDFFF') realLength = 0;
    else realLength = c.getBytes(charset).length; // alternatively also hard code the code point lengths instead of doing conversions (performance micro-optimization)
}


Thanks for that... I'll give it a try.

@DPenner1 - there's no need to posit the complication of 'astral characters' is there? Since the OP is looking at raw byte sizes, any UTF-8 codepoint taking up more than one byte (i.e. most of them) would exhibit the same 'atomic' problem would it not? Let's take an example: let there be 3999 occurences of the character 1 followed by the character €. The three bytes of the latter would get split between chunks

@g00se Not really. The way OP's code works is based on primarily on Java's char, so we're starting from the UTF-16 perspective, not UTF-8. OP uses StringBuilder with UTF-16 Java char, and cannot possibly split € as that is one Java char. My mental compiler has € being pushed to the second chunk, with the first being 3999 occurrences of 1.

The way OP's code works is based on primarily on Java's char Actually it isn't (rightly), it's based on codepoints. If it were, e.g. by using the likes of "".toCharArray() it might run into problems caused by a single codepoint being represented by more than one char, but it doesn't

@g00se Might just be a matter of semantics, but I again disagree. The first step in OP's loop is: String c = input.substring(i, i+1); // charAt(i);. The code is clearly based on going one Java char at a time even it the value does end up in a String datatype instead of char.

Sorry - you're right. I'd made the assumption that by now String.length() would have been fixed to reflect the number of codepoints it contains - it hasn't ;)

It may be way easier to try to change DB settings (and possibly update):
MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED will allow way more characters (32k).
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6
If that is not an option, as pointed in another answer, Java uses UTF-16, you are storing UTF-8 it seems. Use some function to transfer between charsets (sorry, can't help on that part) and then partition. I would not go that low unless absolutely needed.

The charset you use in the algorithm to split the string should be the same as the one you pass in the connection string used to connect to the database.
Example: if you use UTF-16 as parameter to your split() and UTF-8 to connect to the database, you may have:
Java side parts of e.g. length 1999 in chars, and 4000 bytes but once inserted in the DB, LENGTH() and LENGTHB() will return 1999 chars and 2220 bytes resp. I let you do the testing if you are using UTF-8 in Java and your connection string is using ISO8859...
While doing the same exercise with both UTF-8 for the split() and the DB connection will give both sides 3597 chars and 4000 bytes (on the same example string).
So the first thing to do is to check the settings of your DB connection, the second one would be to refactor your split() function which is inefficient: you are looping thousand of times, you could loop reducing the size in chars of the string (using substring) by (the size in bytes - 4000) / 4 until it's below the 4000 bytes barrier, that should reduce the looping to a few tens.
